# How to find certain text between quotes

Tags: ruby, flickr

I'm trying to write a Ruby script that will take the Flickr BBCode from an image and only find the actual image link and ignore all of the other stuff.

The BBCode from Flickr looks like this:

```
<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/user/9049969465/" title="Wiggle Wiggle by Anonymous, on Flickr"><img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2864/92917419471_248187_c.jpg" width="800" height="526" alt="Wiggle Wiggle"></a>
```

and I'm trying to get my output to be just the link, so: https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2864/92917419471_248187_c.jpg

So far, my code is this

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'

str1 = ""

puts "What text would you like me to use? "
text = gets

text.scan(/"([^"]*)"/) { str1 = $1}

puts str1
```

and I need to know how I can scan through the input and only find the part that starts at https and ends with the quote. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to [parse HTML with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Instead, use an HTML parser.  Something like Nokogiri http://nokogiri.org/

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse '<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/user/9049969465/" title="Wiggle Wiggle by Anonymous, on Flickr"><img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2864/92917419471_248187_c.jpg" width="800" height="526" alt="Wiggle Wiggle"></a>'

doc.css('a').each do |link|
  puts link.attr(:href)
end
```

Comment: +1, yes, lest ["Russian hackers pwn your webapp"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/128421).

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't even know about that. Back to fix my code. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should really use a proper HTML parser if you're trying to parse HTML.

For example, this is trivial in [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/):

```
require 'nokogiri'

bbcode = %Q[<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/user/9049969465/" title="Wiggle Wiggle by Anonymous, on Flickr"><img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2864/92917419471_248187_c.jpg" width="800" height="526" alt="Wiggle Wiggle"></a>]

Nokogiri::HTML(bbcode).css('a')[0]['href']
# => "http://www.flickr.com/photos/user/9049969465/"
```

You'll obviously have to add some error checking in there, but that's the basics.

Comment: And, of course, `css('a')[0]` can be simplified to `at_css('a')`.

Comment: @theTinMan yes, I did the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML (<<-eol)
<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/user/9049969465/" title="Wiggle Wiggle by Anonymous, on Flickr"><img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2864/92917419471_248187_c.jpg" width="800" height="526" alt="Wiggle Wiggle"></a>
eol
doc.at_css("a")['href']
# => "http://www.flickr.com/photos/user/9049969465/"
doc.at("a")['href']
# => "http://www.flickr.com/photos/user/9049969465/"
```